# iTerm shows many fork failed errors, anybody knows why?

Tags: git, grep, iterm2

My iTerm always giving these errors:
`grep-flag-available:1: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable`, `env_default:1: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable
[5]    90816 broken pipe` & `nvm_supports_source_options:2: fork failed: resource temporarily unavailable`. Sometimes it's also giving me `git fork` error.

I have been googling about this problem for a while but cannot figure out why, anybody has any idea?
[image]

Comment: When does this happen? When you open the terminal, before running a command? Does it happen again after each command you run?

Comment: Check `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`/`~/.bash_profile`. A software you installed (`node.js` f.e.) has added one or more lines there. Comment them one by one (or in blocks) and restart the terminal until you find the buggy one.

Comment: This happens to me randomly. Sometimes at the beginning when I start my iTerm, but sometimes all going well and suddenly when I open a new tab, this error would show up again. When this happened, I would have to quit my iTerm.

Comment: OK I will try to do that! Thanks!